# Write an interpreter for "interpreter"

Tags: code-golf, interpreter

I just created a language on the spot, and it's called "interpreter". Called as such because the only valid word is "interpreter"!
A sample program in "interpreter" looks like this:

```
interpreter interpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter
```

It may look meaningless, but the language works like:

- `interpreter` initializes the accumulator to zero.
- `interpreterinterpreter` adds one to the accumulator.
- `interpreterinterpreterinterpreter` subtracts one from the accumulator.
- `interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter` multiplies the accumulator by 2.
- `interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter` divides the accumulator by 2.
- `interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter` outputs the accumulator.

### Rules

- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- Shortest program in **bytes** wins.
- Your program should work for all test cases.
- You may assume that all code entered is valid.
- The first command will always be `interpreter`.
- There will always be a single space between each command.
- Floating point division, not integer division.
- Trailing newlines are allowed.

### Testcases

```
interpreter interpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter -> 1
interpreter interpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter -> 3
interpreter interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter -> 1
interpreter interpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter interpreter interpreterinterpreter interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter -> outputs 2, then outputs 1, then outputs 1
```

Comment: Should we consider that no invalid code will be submitted to our program? (eg behaviour is not defined for invalid code?)

Comment: You may assume that all code entered will be valid (editing that into rules)

Comment: You say that `interpreter` initializes the accumulator to 0. Will there always be one at the start of the program?

Comment: Can we assume too that there will only be a single space between the instructions?

Comment: @OliverNi Yes, there will always be one `interpreter` at the beginning.

Comment: @Kaddath Yes...

Comment: Will there always be only one print?

Comment: @OliverNi No, not necessarily

Comment: @Arnauld Oops, sorry$

Comment: this looks like deadfish but with worse commands.

Comment: Can we output characters instead of numbers?

Comment: As long as it is clear that the output is a number, that is fine. For example, outputting `"1"` instead of `1` is perfectly acceptable, however, outputting `true` instead of `1` is not

Comment: @Arnauld float division

Comment: In case someone needs this language in a production environment, here is a [compiler to c](https://tio.run/##lY3NbsIwEITvPIUFitauE/Nz6CU4LwJI3iQGFhnbsl0uFc@eEvXSW8Xlm9FoNHPDB@YhUSyND6OdHphY1mYiX2yKyb7I/vj/43fsZNrFEHwOzioXLhxW5Af3NVq2z2WkoK7d0b/67I7kufgGybPK0VExzKg7Rk66O0CcN898WY3LGgXUgGu9m@XjV5pmppRQ9xpQb@B04KSc9Zdybbai@jwJdQvkTWuESjY6HCzva5ifQfZCQvsE0U4/)

Comment: @Razetime the point was to be like deadfish, but modified such that tricks using the length of a command (such as in Arnauld's answer) could be used

Comment: Can we have a trailing newline?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing yes

Answer (score 7):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 71 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.split` `.map(i=>(n=i.length%6)?s=[,s/2,s*2,s-1,s+1,0][n]:print(s))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VNNC8IwDL3vV4SK0LqufhxEHJ0n/4G3MVgZnavMWZqyi/jb58CLN5kOxUPCSwjk5YV3Uq3Cwhnro3bTlbJDmaBAWxufQy7OylIjE9pII2rdHH01XbMdypTjfMVx1ke05Bgu@SJLm2xrnWk8Rca6OA0ASF9pZ53uMzzh1@0hkPCPVg1iACNMjHbQu1z@TPMffgK@I2aQBaK8uL0qKkqRg2EgE7jCw07koNFDoVDDhEAIYWhYDGVvsxhurLsD)

#### How?

The length of an *interpreter* instruction is \$11\times k,\:1\le k \le 6\$, which gives \$[11,22,33,44,55,66]\$. When applying a modulo \$6\$, this maps to \$[5,4,3,2,1,0]\$. This is shorter than dividing by \$11\$ and allows us to easily identify the *output* instruction (size \$66\$, mapped to \$0\$) which behaves differently from the other ones.

---

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 80 bytes

This version is also based on the length of the instruction modulo \$6\$ but doesn't use any lookup table. It updates the accumulator with a single statement, using arithmetic and bitwise operations.

This is rather pointless in JS but [does save a few bytes in C](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219835/58563) (as opposed to a chain of ternary operators).

```javascript
s=>s.split` `.map(i=>(n=i.length%6)?A=A*(6&9/n|n<2)/2+(3>>n-3^2)-2:print(A),A=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VPLCsIwELz3K5aKktiXRBBfifTgH3gTpaGkNlJjSIIX9dtrwYs3qYriZRiGhZ2dYff8xG1upHbRaVwXtLaU2djqSroMsvjANZKUIUVlXAm1c2V3hBcpTfto1Jsk6qLmBCckQEPGVDTcEhyRqTZSOZTiMKUDXM/WHoDfKMJoIxqEB/5cbkP98K1VrRzAByY@dtCrXv4s8x82Ad8J09t4cXE0S56XCNkQJAbK4Az3l/JXwjrIuRXQ8SGAIJB4BgWyDV5xfQM)

```
           | n =        | multiply by:  | add:
 operation | length % 6 | (6&9/n|n<2)/2 | (3>>n-3^2)-2
-----------+------------+---------------+--------------
 clear     |      5     |       0       |      0
 increment |      4     |       1       |      1
 decrement |      3     |       1       |     -1
 double    |      2     |       2       |      0
 halve     |      1     |      0.5      |      0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <sup><s>113</s> \$\cdots\$  <s>113</s></sup> 111 bytes

Saved <s>3</s> 6 bytes thanks to the man himself [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)!!!
Added 6 bytes to accommodate floating-point division.
Saved 2 bytes thanks to [ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)!!!

```c
float a;c;f(char*s){for(;*s;c?a=a*(6&9/c|c<2)/2+(3>>c-3^2)-2:printf("%f ",a),++s)for(c=1;*++s&&*s-32;c=++c%6);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VRta8IwEP7urzgKLUnT4tqCMGPdp/2K1UE4E1dwbWkCk7n@9XVprU5kMBSZLB@Oy91zr@EJhivEtlXrUhgQHLki@CJqX9OtKmvCfc3xQaTCJxPvfowfOIvpOGYkmc8xTJ5jGsbTqs4Lo4jjKnACQQPGNO2CMY24by@e5@swiTmmjKE7obxpbQC8irwgdLQdgT19UTBSG/20gBS2joXIuqqllXCk/24@R3UCuLzQWfXhCogrjXNpJ/9q3zd8BfibVTb8iDlyU0k0cjmQJ@oWnXSi12KIINoHWGoC6QiYF0u5sfA7Pqgz0Pm7LBXZZ6PjweAfLBwY69EUdsw9Yq/NtWNwD1jwE7@0/kOfp5D9J5I5rs6crHjsgXoKbqazwg5hApD0G6@IoT9EF@HNj@126KwZNe0nqrVY6TZ8@wI)

Comment: [110 bytes](https://tio.run/##1VRba4MwFH73VxwES@KFNrrtIZn0ab9i9iHE2AmbFSOsTPzrc0ernZTBaCkrC5xwLl9yLuGLCrZKdZ0SUmREvcjKNbTJdhURrhGeNxoqZsJFa7FwTRCFGFBUyFg5D2vl3KPcoUQo4XrFpce4DBgPXcnlMuRllRd1RmwnBduXVLRthw54k3lBqNVYgGvIDLU2tXneQAyNjRBdlZXGHWb67@5zVNuHyxOdlR@ugLhSO5dW8q/mfcNXgL8ZZStmzNH7UqtapyN5WD/oqN8GLQQGbDqAfAbSEzAvUr1H@EqM6iOY/EPvMjLdRpejwz16BHjegKZwYO6MvXjXgcEDYCNO4hrjxzpPIdMnkdiOSeykeBqAhoOTmKTAJmofNP3GZ6SmP5wugpsvrHasrLXa7lNlr3JruuD9Cw) by using modulos. In C, it might be more efficient to use a formula instead of ternary operators, though.

Comment: The last test case [in the original post](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/219810/1) suggests that it's supposed to be float division. (I've asked the OP to clarify.)

Comment: @Arnauld That's a good one - thank! :D Handling fp division would add +6 (`float `) to the byte count. :(

Comment: FP division has been confirmed by the OP. :-/ It doesn't fix the division, but porting the formula of my alternate JS version would save 3 bytes: [107 bytes](https://tio.run/##1VRRa4MwEH7vrzgEJTGKU6GwpnZP@xWzg3DGTtisGGFlzr8@F612UgqjpawsD8fdly93lwtf0N0gti1ywVOCL6K0Fa3TbUm4rThjQ4CRz20dWZat3DDgGDGG5pxyfBCRsMncuvfwE5cB9QJGwtUK3fA5oG6wKMosr1JimAkYjqC8aVoNwJvIckJn9Qz06stCJVWlntYQQW1oiiyLUmoLE/93@BzXcODyQmfVhyswrnSdSzv5V/O@4SvA34yy4RPlyF0hsZLJIB6/G3TYmd4LwAd/PKDFDKQTYJYncqfpd3xwl6CyD7lNyZiNegNgHxAOjPVsCnvlTtSrc@0V3BPW/Ghf6v1Dn8eU8ZOIDVPFRpw/9kS1ADNWca4vUTkg6Q8/JRU9cTp3b750t0NnzaxpvzB9FRvVuu/f)

Comment: @Arnauld Nice one - thanks! :D l fixed the fp too, thanks for the update.

Comment: @ceilingcat Nice one - thanks! :D

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
#€g"=;·<>0"sè».Võ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f@VHTmnQlW@tD223sDJSKD684tFsv7PDW//8z80pSiwqKUoGkAhKbbGFSmApUUEGSEbTzCgA)

+2 bytes thanks to a bug, corrected by Makonede

-1 byte thanks to Command Master!

### How it works

```
#€g"=;·<>0"sè».Võ - Program. Push the input I to the stack
#                 - Split I on spaces
 €g               - Lengths of €ach
   "=;·<>0"       - Push "=;·<>0"
           s      - Swap, moving the lengths to the top of the stack
            è     - Index into string, 0-based and modularly
             »    - Join by newlines
              .V  - Run as 05AB1E code
                õ - Push the empty string
```

This takes a similar approach to my [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219843/66833), translating into 05AB1E then running. This only beats Jelly because the increment commands can go in strings in 05AB1E, but not in Jelly

We don't need to bother with any syntax nonsense to reset the accumulator in 05AB1E. Instead, as all the commands operate on the top value, we just push a 0 to the top of the stack

| interpreter command | Equivalent 05AB1E command | What it does in 05AB1E |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `interpreter` | `0` | Pushes `0` to the ToS (top of stack) |
| `interpreterinterpreter` | `>` | Increments the ToS |
| `interpreterinterpreterinterpreter` | `<` | Decrements the ToS |
| `interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter` | `·` | Doubles the ToS |
| `interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter` | `;` | Halves the ToS |
| `interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter` | `=` | Prints the ToS without popping it |

We push an empty string at the end to prevent implicit output. If nothing has been output by the transpiled interpreter code, 05AB1E would output the ToS. We push the empty string so that if no output has been produced, 05AB1E outputs the empty string instead

Comment: This is invalid because 1. there is implicit output and 2. the lack of separation between `0`s causes multiple `interpreter`s in a row to push a string of multiple zeros. Both of these issues can be seen when running the program `interpreter interpreter`. The former can be fixed by prepending `õ?`, and the latter by replacing `0` with `¾`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8FZ75UdNa9KVbK0PbbexO7RPqfjwCi@9sP//M/NKUosKilKBpAISm2xhUpgKVFBBkhG08woA)

Comment: @Makonede Well, I don't fully understand how that works, but I'll take your word for it. Thanks!

Comment: Well, `õ?` first outputs an empty string with no trailing newline. This essentially outputs nothing while clearing implicit output; implicit output will only ever trigger if no explicit output was ever triggered before that. So, this triggers explicit output while outputting nothing and simultaneously prevents implicit output. As for `¾`, it simply pushes the `counter_variable` which is by default zero and doesn't get updated in your code. While a streak of multiple `¾`'s pushes multiple zeros (example: `¾¾¾` pushes three zeros), a streak of multiple zeros pushes a string of them (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) (example: `000` pushes `"000"`).

Comment: can you do `#€g"=;·<>¾"sèJ.Võ` to disable implicit input?

Comment: @CommandMaster That depends on if a trailing newline is allowed, but given that it normally is, I've assumed yes and will revert if the OP says otherwise

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `rDO`, 13 bytes

```
⌈vL`…½d‹›0`İĖ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=rDO&code=%E2%8C%88vL%60%E2%80%A6%C2%BDd%E2%80%B9%E2%80%BA0%60%C4%B0%C4%96&inputs=interpreter%20interpreterinterpreter%20interpreterinterpreter%20interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter%20interpreterinterpreterinterpreter%20interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter%20interpreter%20interpreterinterpreter%20interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter%20interpreterinterpreter&header=&footer=)

Vyxal port of [@caird coinheringaahing’s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219846/101522).

Explanation:

```
               # Implicit input
⌈              # Split on " "
 vL            # Length of each command
   `…½d‹›0`    # Push "…½d‹›0" 'D' flag - treat as raw string
           İ   # Index into string
            Ė  # Exec as Vyxal code
               # 'O' flag - disable implicit output


The commands in `…½d‹›0`:
… - Print without popping
½ - Halve
d - Double
‹ - Decrement
› - Increment
0 - Push 0
```

Comment: Very nicely done!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>138</s> bytes

Easy translation of the *interpreter language* instructions:

```python
for i in[len(o)/11for o in input().split(' ')]:
 if i==1:a=0
 if i==2:a=a+1
 if i==3:a=a-1
 if i==4:a=a*2
 if i==5:a=a/2
 if i==6:print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/Py2/SCFTITMvOic1TyNfU9/QECSSDxQBooLSEg1NveKCnMwSDXUFdc1YKy6FzDSFTFtbQ6tEWwMYxwjISdQ2hHGNQVxdONcExNUygnFNQVx9ONfMqqAoM69EI1Hz/38gnVpUUJQKJBWQ2ISFSWFykW0LSZYrUEEFNfxCrjOo4DoA)

In the first line:

1. takes the input
2. split the instructions separated by a space
3. divide by 11 (the lenght of the base word `interpreter`) to get the corresponding operation

The subsequent `if` execute the operations on the accumulator.

*EDIT:* theoretical improvements, code not modified (see version 2). Anyway, thanks for the suggestions!

*-4 bytes thanks to @expressjs123*

*-3 bytes thanks to @ElPedro*

---

**VERSION 2**

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>97</s> <s>96</s> 93 bytes

Improved the selection of the instructions simply by using list slicing.

*-41 bytes compared to original version.*

*-1 byte thanks to @ElPedro*

*-3 bytes thanks to @Zaelin Goodman*

```python
a=0
for i in[len(o)//11for o in input().split()]:
 a-=[a,-1,1,-a,a/2,0][i-1]
 if i>5:print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9HWgCstv0ghUyEzLzonNU8jX1Nf39AQJJQPFAKigtISDU294oKcTCAda8WlkKhrG52oo2uoY6ijm6iTqG@kYxAbnalrGMulkJmmkGlnalVQlJlXopGo@f8/kE4tKihKBZIKSGzCwqQwuci2hSTLFaigghp@IdcZQyekBzD8FejiFQA)

Comment: Using shorthands like `+=`, `-=` etc saves bytes

Comment: `split()` splits on space by default for -3

Comment: Save another 1 with `i>5` instead of `i==6` as there will not be more than 6 `interpreter`s in a command

Comment: 89 bytes by switching to -= rather than = and using modulo rather than division [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9HWgCstv0ghUyEzLzonNU8jX1PVDCSQDxQAooLSEg1NveKCnEwgHWvFpZCoaxttoJOob6Sjm6hjqKNrqJMYG50Zy6WQmaaQaWNoVVCUmVeikaj5/z@QTi0qKEoFkgpIbMLCpDC5yLaFJMsVqKCCGn4h1xlDJ6QHMPwV6OIVAA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @Zaelin Goodman, thank you, updated the list selection, but i prefere to leave the division logic ;)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>128</s> <s>105</s> <s>90</s> 86 bytes

```php
foreach(explode(' ',$argn)as$v)($i=strlen($v)%6)?$c-=[0,$c/2,-$c,1,-1,$c][$i]:print$c;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLUhOTMzRSKwpy8lNSNdQV1HVUEovS8zQTi1XKNDVUMm2LS4pyUvM0gDxVM017lWRd22gDHZVkfSMdXZVkHUMdXUMgLzZaJTPWqqAoM69EJdn6/38gnVpUUJQKJBWQ2GQLk6uYJOOwM//lF5Rk5ucV/9d1AwA)

<s>Actually counting the number of parts split by `p` rather than counting `interpreter`, so that any word that contains "p" would work.</s>

EDIT: saved 23 bytes by using an array (inspired by other answers)

EDIT 2: another 15 bytes with @Arnauld the Great's modulo 6. Basically a port of his answer now

EDIT3: 4 bytes less with an array of values to subtract instead of an array to assign

Comment: Because you want to avoid using too many `$c`, it's shorter to do it that way in PHP: [86 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLUhOTMzRSKwpy8lNSNdQV1HVUEovS8zQTi1XKNDVUMm2LS4pyUvM0gDxVM017lWRd22gDHZVkfSMdXZVkHUMdXUMgLzZaJTPWqqAoM69EJdn6/38gnVpUUJQKJBWQ2GQLk6uYJOOwM//lF5Rk5ucV/9d1AwA)

Comment: @Arnauld yeah thats what I was doing ^^ but it was a [87 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLUhOTMzRSKwpy8lNSNdQV1HVUEovS8zQTi1XKNDVUMm2LS4pyUvM0gDxVM017lWRt22gDHV2VZH0jHZVkHV1DHUMQLzZaJTPWqqAoM69EJdn6/38gnVpUUJQKJBWQ2GQLk6uYJOOwM//lF5Rk5ucV/9d1AwA) with a `+=`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>120</s> 71 bytes

```bash
o=(. =0 ++ -- *=2 /=2)
for i;do
((x${o[n=${#i}/11]},n-6))||echo $x
done
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifpqFZ/T/fVkNPwdZAQVtbQVdXQcvWSEHf1kiTKy2/SCHTOiWfS0OjQqU6PzrPVqVaObNW39AwtlYnT9dMU7OmJjU5I19BpYIrJT8v9X8tF1eaQmZeSWpRQVEqkERmExYmhUmJPSRZr0AFFYR9Q5R3yHUJVRwIjmclW1uFnMTiEoXkxOJUKwVbWyUuukXEAEYPfZL0//8A)

#### Credits

- Saved 4 bytes from both answers thanks to @Neil
- Saved 49 bytes thanks to @DigitalTrauma

Comment: Your first answer doesn't need `x=0` because it's guaranteed to be the first operation.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 80 bytes

```php
foreach(explode(' ',$argn)as$v)$a-=[$a/2,-$a,1,-1,$a][strlen($v)%6-1]??!print$a;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk0/KLUhOTMzRSKwpy8lNSNdQV1HVUEovS8zQTi1XKNFUSdW2jVRL1jXR0VRJ1DHV0DYGysdHFJUU5qXkaQAWqZrqGsfb2igVFmXklKonW//8D6dSigqJUIKmAxCZbmBSmAhVUkGQE7bzyL7@gJDM/r/i/rhsA)

**Explanation**

```php
$a                 // accumulator
-=                 // subtract operation result and assign to accumulator
[$a/2,-$a,1,-1,$a] // array of operations (divide, multiply, subtract, add, reset)
[strlen($v)%6-1]   // modulo 6 of command length, minus 1
                   // this way the print command (-1) will not be present in array
??                 // array key does not exist?
!print$a;          // print accumulator and toggle the boolean value of print's return
                   // toggle is required, because print always returns 1
                   // and we don't want to modify accumulator value, so !1 == 0
```

**Credits**

- Main idea for performing commands from [Kaddath's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219818/100869)
- Modulo operation from [Arnauld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219817/100869)

Comment: Nice improvement! I'm not used to the `??` operator yet (actually I don't use PHP much nowadays except here).. +1

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
ḲẈị“HḤ“øȮ”j⁾’‘¤Vṛ“
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk0Pd3U83N39qGGOx8MdS4DU4R0n1j1qmJv1qHHfo4aZjxpmHFoS9nDnbKDM////M/NKUosKilKBpAISm2xhUpgKVFBBkhG08woA)

### How it works

```
ḲẈị“HḤ“øȮ”j⁾’‘¤Vṛ“ - Main link. Takes a string I on the left
Ḳ                  - Split I at spaces
 Ẉ                 - Get the length of each section
              ¤    - Group into a nilad:
   “HḤ“øȮ”         -   [["H", "Ḥ"], ["ø", "Ȯ"]]
           ⁾’‘     -   ["’", "‘"]
          j        -   Join; ["H", "Ḥ", "’", "‘", "ø", "Ȯ"]
  ị                - Index into the string, modularly and 1-indexed
               V   - Execute as Jelly code
                 “ - Yield the empty string
                ṛ  - Replace with the empty string to suppress automatic output
```

This program translates interpreter into Jelly and then runs it as Jelly code. First, only the lengths of each command actually matter. The lengths are `[11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66]`, which are unique modulo 6. The commands are transliterated as follows:

| interpreter command | Length | Length mod 6 | Jelly command |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `interpreter` | 11 | 5 | `ø` |
| `interpreterinterpreter` | 22 | 4 | `‘` |
| `interpreterinterpreterinterpreter` | 33 | 3 | `’` |
| `interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter` | 44 | 2 | `Ḥ` |
| `interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter` | 55 | 1 | `H` |
| `interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter` | 66 | 0 | `Ȯ` |

As Jelly uses modular indexing, we don't need to bother to modulo the lengths, we can just go ahead and into the command list.

Most of these commands are pretty obvious and are direct translations from the spec (e.g. `‘` is Jelly's increment command, `Ḥ` is double etc.). However, `ø` is slightly different (and I think this is the only time I've every used it).

`ø` is a syntax command that tells Jelly to begin a new niladic chain. This basically tells Jelly to throw away everything before it and to reset, using `0` as the argument for the new command. As we're outputting as we go, its actually perfectly fine to "throw away" the previous commands, because they're no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>84</s></sup> 82 bytes

```python
n=0
for c in input().split():l=len(c)%10;n+=[-n,1,-1,n,-n/2,0][l-1];l==6==print(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rU9BCsMgELz7Ci9FbbXVBnpI2JeIp2CpIBsxKaSvt7an3kqCsOwOwzAzm17LY8KurMAYKwia3KdMRxqwTnouXJznFEO9fYTokY/iYPSAJ7AKpZHKSJQKL1epnY3KuCEC3ABSDrhwFKXakq9n@Hha7Y5dT6hf/chXUarI55R93fQH/6e3QLI7ZVM4baBo8cveGg3avQE)

-2 bytes Oliver Ni

Comment: [82](https://tio.run/##rU9BCsMgELz7Ci9FbbXVBnpI2JeIp2CpIBsxKaSvt7an3kqCsOwOwzAzm17LY8KurMAYKwia3KdMRxqwTnouXJznFEO9fYTokY/iYPSAJ7AKpZHKSJQKL1epnY3KuCEC3ABSDrhwFKXakq9n@Hha7Y5dT6hf/chXUarI55R93fQH/6e3QLI7ZVM4baBo8cveGg3avQE)

Comment: [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##rU9BCsMgELz7Ci9FLdpqAz0k7EuCp2CpIBuxFuzrre2pt5IgLLvDMMzMxle@rzjUAoyxiqDJbU10oR7bxGfm4vSIwbc7BggO@SIORk@oYEapjDRSocTzRWo7B2XsFACuADF5zBxFba7ka@k/lrO2x2Ek1BW38CJqE7kUk2ub/uD/9BZIdqdsCqcdFD1@2VujQ7s3) using Arnauld's suggestion on my answer

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 31 bytes

```
Ｆ⪪Ｓ ≡№ιi¹≔⁰θ²≦⊕θ³≦⊖θ⁴≦⊗θ⁵≦⊘θ⟦Ｉθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tY89C8IwEEB3f8XhlEAFP5c6iQ52EARHcYhprIGYtMlFB/G3x4gKLbhUdDmO9x4Hx4/McsNUCAdjgWxKJZFkuvS4QSt1QWgCXehSCu4ikR@BzI3XSGTE8oGvHc6cgEEKM@dkoUk/gYpOn3SYwoqVL5FpbsVJaBR5LRnVk4X4lIwbifF71dCTul4ydX7bXByYV5jCOn6CZDtnDklFd1HdQohI2NKKOKG2f43brPCDotWJ/73SCb2zugM) Explanation:

```
Ｆ⪪Ｓ
```

Split the input on spaces and loop over each word.

```
≡№ιi
```

Count the number of `i`s in each word.

```
¹≔⁰θ²≦⊕θ³≦⊖θ⁴≦⊗θ⁵≦⊘θ⟦Ｉθ
```

Perform the appropriate operation on the accumulator depending on the number of `i`s.

Note that a `switch` is shorter than looking up the results in an array as I don't have to initialise the accumulator.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 206 bytes

```
@set/ps=
@set t=@set "s=
%t%%s:nterpreter=%
%t%%s: =&set/an%
%t%%s:set/aniiiiii=call:c%
%t%%s:iiiii=/=2%
%t%%s:iiii=*=2%
%t%%s:iii=-=1%
%t%%s:ii=+=1%
%t%%s:i==0%
@set/an%s%
@exit/b
:c
@echo %n%
```

Takes input on STDIN. Works by performing substitutions on the input string to produce Batch code which is then executed.

Answer (score 0):

## Java, <s>137</s> 129 bytes

```
s->{var x=0d;int l;for(var w:s.split(" ")){if((l=w.length()/11)==6)System.out.println(x);x-=new double[]{x,-1,1,-x,x/2,0}[l-1];}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVA9b4MwEN3zK05MuAUndOhQ4iyZO2VEDK5jiKkxyD6CK8Rvp66Cqq6p2pPO9/ne3bnhV5425/elH960EiA0dw5euTIwbSDImnfIMZhrp87Qhmp8QqtMXZTAbe3I2vwlTWCkAypNq8EIVJ2hx864oZV2fwMdQLDFpYdJGQTPdonOq86ujDC@OOp6rTCOICJk0mykWpoaLzHZZlmuqlgz9kxOHw5lS7sBaR@AqE3sSe6ZkSOEsCinXeIfs8SnQR@eEr8NOhc6zcp8npf8e2FBuRCyD/MCTNreyvDCD//X6Xtc@IOOuyj@75SI3D533szLJw)

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to [branboyer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/94107).*

Comment: This challenge requires floating point precision, which could be done by changing the int's to double's [like this. 137 bytes](https://tio.run/##xZDBboQgEIbv@xQTT9Iqu/bQQyl76bmnPRoPFNFiEQzgSmN8dkujafbWpJdOMvBnmP9jMh27sryrP9ZhfFOSA1fMOXhlUsN8gBh73Xnm43U1soY@vqYXb6VuywqYbR3am7@ji0Q8eqlwM2rupdH4xWg39sI@b6YzcLq6/DzXJsIFBHoiUntQpDF2B8P05LAblPRpAglCs6ITVkK3/j1Fx6IgskkVpY/o8um86LEZPR6i0SudBkQC1WKCjV9W8ykL90UW8ph3D1k4xlxKlRcVWZaV/IzOMeNcDPHLCBJ2sCKecKP/t/yr/KvvRiZoW8dyWNYv)

Comment: [My golfed version of the corrected version 134 bytes](https://tio.run/##vZK9boMwEID3PMWJyZbAhA4dSsnSuVNGxOAaQ02NjWwTXCGenboCVV1TJb3hfDrfffdjd/RCk67@WIfxTQoGTFJr4ZUKBfMBgux@66gLx0WLGvpwi87OCNWWFVDTWrwHf0sXiGR0QpJmVMwJrciLVnbsuXnekk7AitUmp7nWAc7BF8dcKAcyb7TZwTA9WWIHKRyKIMJ4Fg1CspiI5Kp17winWYaL4hGfP63jPdGjI0NIdFIhj3OfFIpPsBUoq9nHSRZnceJjnz7Ex6WUSVbly7LmW99pGhQjlDE@hIqBw81geNDwy/6z@xoTbhBxFeJ@o0Q4//kW91vu/7zQDdexHJb1Cw) -3 by putting `l=...` in the if statement and `x-=...`

Comment: [129 bytes](https://tio.run/##vVGxbsIwEN3zFSemWEocQqUOuKFD13ZiRAwmccDUsSPbIamifHt6qKitqg5QQW@w787v7t497/mBx/vidZRVbayHPca08VLRZ@k8C4K62SiZQ664c/DCpYY@ALRT3nnu8ToYWUCFr@HSW6m3qzVwu3XkBD7aV@ey0bmXRtMno11TCfvwUbSAPBtdvOgP3EKXTQsmtQfFSmPDY6qdO@pqJX04gQkhvSzDUGUtVUJv/S4kSZqSLLsnyzfnRUVN42mNfb3SYUdYF2datFAYJC5W676L4jRKo7iLumQWTYeVitM1G4aRBUkCsgREK6mFg1ZYAVwp04oCpN4I3wqhQfB8BzikbvwcS84n/pPfr1s8nsV3PpkQNgASTmd3SIJ9yp1TnueixpE4QdjaCjzhm//n9CUuXAFxUYvbrYJCH8VFqW8r7//80fUEgSEYxnc) and a 125 byte solution in there too for if newlines in between prints is allowed.

Comment: @branboyer Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 83 -> 73 -> NOW 59 bytes

```powershell
$args|% Le*|%{,$a*!($_%6);$a-=(0,($a/2),-$a,1,-1,$a)[$_%6]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL24RlXBJ1WrRrVaRyVRS1FDJV7VTNNaJVHXVsNAR0MlUd9IU0dXJVHHUEfXEKhCMxqkILb2////mXklqUUFRalAUgGJTbYwuYpJMg47EwA)

Thanks to @mazzy and @ZaelinGoodman

Comment: This doesn't work with the last test case, as a single 'interpreter' should reset A to 0; the first item in your array should be -$a to make it work properly with this method: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL24RrVaJdNWJV4vJzUvvSRD39DQWiVR21ZDVyVRx1BH11AHSOtqqCTqG2nqGGhGq2TqGsZaZ6ZpABnpJaaa1SqJtbX////PzCtJLSooSgWSCkhssoVJYSpQQQVJRtDOKwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: 63 bytes by shuffling some stuff around :) [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL24RlXBJ1WrRrU6M01DUUMlXtVMU7NaJbFWJVHbVsNAR1dDJVHfSFNHJVFH11DHUEdXJVEzGqQqtvb///@ZeSWpRQVFqUBSAYlNtjC5ikkyDjsTAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: [60 bytes?](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL24RlXBJ1WrRrVaRyVRS1FDJV7VTNNaJVHbVsNAR1dDJVHfSBMoo6NrqGOoo6uSqBkNUhFb@////8y8ktSigqJUIKmAxCZbmFzFJBmHnQkA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: [59 bytes?](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyWxKL24RlXBJ1WrRrVaRyVRS1FDJV7VTNNaJVHXVsNAR0MlUd9IU0dXJVHHUEfXEKhCMxqkILb2////mXklqUUFRalAUgGJTbYwuYpJMg47EwA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: @mazzy and ZaelinGoodman you both are too helpful, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + GNU utils, 89

Transpiles to `dc`, then interprets:

```bash
sed -r 's/\S{11}/x/g;s/x{6}/p/g;s/x{5}/2\//g;s/x{4}/2*/g;s/xxx/1-/g;s/xx/1+/g;s/x/0/g'|dc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzg1RUG3SEG9WD8muNrQsFa/Qj/duli/otqsVr8AyjSt1TeK0YdyTIAcLQi7okLfUBfK1DfUhrD0DfTT1WtSkv//z8wrSS0qKEoFkgpIbMLCpDC5yLaFJMsVqKCCGn4h1xlDJ6QHMPwV6OIVAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 29 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
¸®=Êu6)?E=[,E/2EÑEÉEÄT]gZ:OpE
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=uK49ynU2KT9FPVssRS8yRdFFyUXEVF1nWjpPcEU&input=WyJpbnRlcnByZXRlciBpbnRlcnByZXRlcmludGVycHJldGVyIGludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlcmludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlciIsImludGVycHJldGVyIGludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXIgaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlciBpbnRlcnByZXRlcmludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlciBpbnRlcnByZXRlcmludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXIgaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlcmludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlcmludGVycHJldGVyIiwiaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXIgaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlcmludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlciBpbnRlcnByZXRlcmludGVycHJldGVyIGludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlcmludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlciIsImludGVycHJldGVyIGludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXIgaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlciBpbnRlcnByZXRlcmludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlcmludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXIgaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlcmludGVycHJldGVyIGludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlcmludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlciBpbnRlcnByZXRlciBpbnRlcnByZXRlcmludGVycHJldGVyIGludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlcmludGVycHJldGVyaW50ZXJwcmV0ZXJpbnRlcnByZXRlciJdCi1tCg)

- port of [@Arnauld answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/219817/84844) so upvote him!

Answer (score 0):

## [YaBASIC](http://www.yabasic.de), 130 bytes

```
dim c$(1)
n=split(i$,c$())
for j=1 to n
c=mod(len(c$(j)),6)
if c a=a*or(and(6,9/c),c<2)/2+xor(mod(3/2^(c-3),6),2)-2
if !c ?a;
next
```

A basic interpreter interpreter running in an interpreted Basic interpreter...

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##7VPLCsIwELznK9YimNWUYsSCaPVPhDWJENG0pDno19dUL96kPlDBSxhmM5PJZnOiDdVWNdvSgy3GEEqYMm9Ig@2zQeWtCxGJBNIlJPNG2wOoPh8jc0Vd7W3gsRgJRNY67K4OjqniUGq@N47H4g5R5MjsFhRQQcPSc3Ka52KWKRRqITGTo2NkW80kk2uu0kkrERJT2ep6ClY0Z84cQ3PJdIFgmaZAkETC@MqbuMINvk93gcmzh3XKAC/Y8cIrPZrm5/r@wdeA32jnd0zF39m/79d2mqfmDA)

Well, thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s infamous MOD 6 trick, I was able to compress this perfectly readable, easily maintained and expandable 134 byte program:

```
dim c$(1)
n=split(i$,c$())
for j=1 to n
c=len(c$(j))/11
if c=1 a=0
if c=2 a=a+1
if c=3 a=a-1
if c=4 a=a*2
if c=5 a=a/2
if c=6 ?a;
next
```

into the 130-byte bit of opaque confusion seen above!  If I was gonna develop "interpreter" as a product, I know which code-base I'd start with, but really, I'd rather program in DeadFish...

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 66 bytes

```perl
eval((0,'$a=0','$a++','$a--','$a*=2','$a/=2','say$a')[y/i//])for@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDFHQ8NAR10l0dZAHURpa4MpXV0wpWVrBKb1wXRxYqVKorpmdKV@pr5@rGZafpGD2///mXklqUUFRalAUgGJTbYwuYpJMg47819@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQ4P/uokA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
î╜║µI*▄mß┘r>
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=8cbdbae6492adc6de1d9723e&i=interpreter+interpreterinterpreter+interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter%0A%0Ainterpreter+interpreterinterpreter+interpreterinterpreter+interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter+interpreterinterpreterinterpreter+interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter%0A%0Ainterpreter+interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter+interpreterinterpreter+interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter%0A%0Ainterpreter+interpreterinterpreter+interpreterinterpreter+interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter+interpreterinterpreterinterpreter+interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter+interpreter+interpreterinterpreter+interpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreterinterpreter%0A&m=2)

Who needs flags when *compression*? :P